# "next" is not redirecting to expected position

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I am making a wallet app so if someone goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_money/ to add money and they are not logged in they will be redirected to the login page with next there after the user logs in it should be redirected back to add_money but it is being redirected to their profile.

//ADD MONEY VIEW

```
def add_money(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {"next": '/add_money/'})
    else:
        if request.POST:
            username = request.user.username
            add_amount = request.POST['amount']
            wallet = Wallet.objects.filter(username=username).update(add_money(add_amount))
            now = datetime.now()
            trans = Transaction(from_name=username, wallet_id=wallet.id, date=now, amount=add_amount)
            trans.save()
            return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'user': request.user})
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {"next": '/add_money/'})
```

//Login View

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if request.POST['next']:
                    return render(request, '/add_money/')
                return render(request, 'user_profile.html',{'user': user, 'wallet': user.userprofile.wallet_id})
            else:
                return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'error': 'User is not active'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'error': 'User does not exist'})
    else:
        return render(request,'registration/login.html')
```

//login template

```
{% if next %}
        <form action="/login/?next={{next}}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ next }}>
    {%else%}
        <form action="/login/" method="post" >
    {% endif %}
            USERNAME <input type="text" name="username">
            PASSWORD <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="next">
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
```

//add_money template

```
<form action="user_profile.html" method="post">
        Amount:<input type="number" name="amount">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <button type="button" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it how it even manages to get to the account page since you're using the `render` tag as a mixture of `render` and `redirect`.

```
return render(request, '/add_money/')
```

You should return a redirect response back to the next url instead

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['next'])
```

---

Also, you're passing the `next` to the login *template*, not the url

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {"next": '/add_money/'})
```

you should redirect to the login page here as well with next as a get parameter

```
    return  HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next={}'.format('/add_money/')
```

<sub>You should also look into using the provided url reversing methods instead of hard coding urls</sub>

---

You also should remove the whole `if next` in the template and just let the login action be the default for the page

```
{% if next %}
    <form action="/login/?next={{next}}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ next }}>
{%else%}
    <form action="/login/" method="post" >
{% endif %}
```

should be

```
<form method="post" >
```

Comment: i did all of your changes still the same thing is happening

Comment: @RavinKohli - I just realised there are actually a few things wrong here... you need to fix your template also, this will at least get it to go to the right view, but then there are fixed needed in that view also which are outside the scope of this question